# Is the attribute ID read-only in a PATCH request?

Tags: okta, scim, scim2

I'm testing my SCIM implementation as a Service provider. I saw that Okta and Jumpcloud send a PATCH request with the attributes «id» for the operation «replace» :

```
PATCH /Groups/3322
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"
    ],
    "Operations": [
        {
            "op": "replace",
            "value": {
                "id": "3322",
                "displayName": "Test"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The SCIM specifications are :

```
It MUST be a stable, non-reassignable identifier that does not change when the same resource is returned in subsequent requests.  The value of the "id" attribute is always issued by the service provider and MUST NOT be specified by the client.
```

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7643#section-3.1

Even if it's the same value, I return "400 Bad Request", because "ID" is supposed to be read-only. Should I just ignore the attribute "id"? Is it a valid request?

I expect links that explain if it's valid or not.

Answer (score 1):

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7644#page-34

Each operation against an attribute MUST be compatible with the
attribute's mutability and schema as defined in Sections 2.2 and 2.3
of [RFC7643].  For example, a client MUST NOT modify an attribute
that has mutability "readOnly" or "immutable".  However, a client MAY
"add" a value to an "immutable" attribute if the attribute had no
previous value.  **An operation that is not compatible with an
attribute's mutability or schema SHALL return the appropriate HTTP
response status code and a JSON detail error response as defined in
Section 3.12.**